# How to Get Top 5 Rated User in 2 Tables with LINQ using C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have 2 tables, one is Posts another is Comments. These tables contain "RatedPoint" field.

I want to take 5 users who have the highest point.

For example, user ID =1 and its total point 50 in Post table

and it's total point is 25 in Comment table, so its total point is 75

so, i have to look whole members and after choose 5 highest point

It seems a bit complicated, i hope its clear..

I tried something like that

```
var abc= csEntity.Users.Where(u => csEntity.Posts.Any(p => u.Id == p.UserId)).
Take(userCount).OrderByDescending(u => u.Posts.Count).ToList();
```

or..

```
var xyz = csEntity.Posts.Where(p => csEntity.Comments.Any(c => c.UserId == p.UserId));
```

I dont want to use 2 different list if possible.. is it possible to do it in one query?

I could do it with 2 for loops, but i think its a bad idea..

Post TABLE
[image]

Comments TABLE

[image]

As you see, these two tables contain userID and each user has RatedPoint...

I think now its clear

**EDIT:** Maybe a user never write a comment or never write a post just write a comment.. then i think we musnt make equal posts.userId=comments.UserId

Comment: Sounds like you want to `join` the two tables on the user ID, then sort by the sum of the two point counts. A better code example would make it easier for someone to answer with an actual code example (i.e. something better than the hand-waving I'm doing here :) ).

Comment: Can you convert a sql to EF syntax? I guess the sql for this would be Select Top 5 p.ID, SUM(p.Point + com.Point) from posts p, comments com where p.Id = com.Id group by p.id

Comment: @PiyushParashar, i tried it in SQL but it doesnt work.. I mean return wrong result..

Comment: What do you mean by wrong result? It is giving error or unexpected output? Can you please explain?

Comment: I wrote this querty " Select Top 5 p.userId, SUM(p.RatedPoint + com.RatedPoint) from posts p, comments com where p.UserId = com.UserId group by p.UserId"  and result is http://i.imgur.com/YzuYS6W.png   I am editing my question and i will add my table context

Comment: FWIW, a _useful_ improvement to the question would be to provide some C# code that initializes some sample data to use. Screenshots of the actual tables don't really add much (your final comment explaining the disjoint nature of the tables does much more to make the question more understandable).

Comment: @unbalanced is the screenshot truncated? I see the correct result for usertId 3 and 5.

Comment: @PiyushParashar, Aha I see what is the problem.. as I wrote in topic, you dont need to compare if userID is in comments and posts table. Maybe user never write a comment, then just consider posts table for this user. It means doesnt matter match userid in these 2 tables.

Comment: Actually this code almost works  Select Top 5 p.userId, SUM(p.RatedPoint + com.RatedPoint) from posts p, comments com  group by p.UserId   but it shows 11 times much. I mean result should be 4, but it shows 44, result should be 5 but it shows 55    http://i.imgur.com/gaCCfKs.png

Answer (score 0):

Here is a LINQ expression that does what you seem to be asking for:

```
var result = from p in posts
                join c in comments on p.Id equals c.Id
                select new { Id = p.Id, Total = p.Points + c.Points };
```

That provides the actual joined data. Then you can pick the top 5 like this:

```
result.OrderByDescending(item => item.Total).Take(5)
```

Note that the above does assume that both tables always have each user, even if they didn't post or comment. I.e. they would simply have a point count of 0. Your updated question clarifies that in your case, you have potentially disjoint tables, i.e. a user can be in one table but not the other.

In that case, the following should work for you:

```
var leftOuter = from p in posts
                join c in comments on p.Id equals c.Id into groupJoin
                let c = groupJoin.SingleOrDefault()
                select new { Id = p.Id, Total = p.Points + (c == null ? 0 : c.Points) };

var rightAnti = from c in comments
                join p in posts on c.Id equals p.Id into groupJoin
                let p = groupJoin.SingleOrDefault()
                where p == null
                select new { Id = c.Id, Total = c.Points };

var result = leftOuter.Concat(rightAnti);
```

The first LINQ expression does a left outer join. The second LINQ expression does a left anti-join (but I call it "right" because it's effectively the right-join of the original data :) ). I'm using `SingleToDefault()` to ensure that each user is in each table once at most. The code will throw an exception if it turns out they are present more than once (which otherwise would result in that user being represented in the final result more than once).

I admit, I don't know whether the above is the most efficient approach. I think it should be pretty close, since the joins should be optimized (in objects or SQL) and that's the most expensive part of the whole operation. But I make no promises regarding performance. :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. Lambda or linq doesnt matter actually, i just changed it. Well, your code doesnt work right.. http://i.imgur.com/1kcqcWx.png  you can see the result ..

Comment: Ah, okay. I think it would be better for the tables to just always have each user, i.e. with a point count of 0 if they didn't post or comment (for the given table). But you may not have a way to change the tables, or there may be other reasons for keeping the way they are. I'll update my answer with an option that should work for your scenario.

Comment: thank you for your nice answer. But When I use like that, an exception occurs because of singleordefault and i used firstordefault, this time it gives me 14 result but they are wrong results.. As I wrote in topic, an user maybe never write a comment, or maybe never write a post. Then we musnt care if they are in 2 tables or not. If an user is in just post table, also should be counted, doesnt matter if its not also in comments...